# Formula for number of 6 letter words from English alphabet if there is repetion and ordering

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Is there a formula or method to find the number of 6-letter words from the English alphabet if repetition is allowed, but they must appear in alphabetical order?

Type what you know about how many words there'd be if they didn't also need to be in alphabetical order...

Limitless repetition however ordering wasn't specified. I'm so confused as to how to combine the formula for repetition and ordering.

I know the number six letter words that do not have to appear in alphabetical order would be $26^6$.  But when I try to count only those words that are alphabetically ordered, I get stuck.

Comment: @MayankDeora I know if the ordering was included it would be 26^6 but i dont know what to do with the ordering since it wasnt specified what order

Comment: No, with order NOT included, the answer would be 26^6.

Comment: I think you can take "alphabetic order" to be the ordering abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.

Comment: I suggest that the six letters must be arranged in alphabetic order, where repetition is allowed. Examples of such words: "deegpz", "achiim," whereas the word "example" does not count, because a, m, p, l appear after x in the word. Nor does "mseurm" because the letters to not appear in alphabetic order.

Comment: @amWhy what is a formula for this

Comment: The first and better thing is to reason with your mind, rather than just the formula. We can count all the words with repetition but NOT ordered, and then subtract all unordered words. We could also see that The starting letter of ordered words will determine the number of choices for the second letter, which will determine the number for the third letter.

Comment: See the [linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945771/what-are-the-total-number-of-ordered-permutations-of-a-list-of-elements-possibl) and its answer.  It is identical to yours, but instead of letters, it deals with non-decreasing order (repetion allowed)

Comment: @amWhy the thing is to complete what I'm doing I need a formula example 26^6 and whatever else would make the answer accurate. The linked question actual isn't the same since the ordering is specified

Comment: You've got a formula and explanation to use at the linked question.  You need to figure out n and a are with respect to your question. Know, you know the ordering (alphabetical order)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if words like "aaaaaa", "iaiwiz" will be counted as one word, but if so, then

Assume the 6 letter word is composed by randomly chosen English alphabet, then combination of each letter is 26. So with ordering and repetition, the number of way of forming the 6 letter word$=26*26*26*26*26$

Comment: I believe that the six letters must be arranged in alphabetic order, where repetition is allowed. Examples of such words: deegpz, achiim, whereas the word "example" does not count.

Comment: But this would not take into consideration ordering , just repetition

Comment: @Nick  Your edit is the easy way of answering the question.  The question specifically asks to take both order and repetition. Your answer, as Jaydee notes, is pretty straightforward, if you were not answering the OPs question, but rather, answering a much easier question